# ¿Cómo cambiar columnas a filas?

Tags: r

Tengo unos datos de concentración de contaminantes atmosféricos organizados en 15 variables, entre las cuales se encuentra la fecha, el lugar, y los contaminantes. En esta última se encuentran los contaminantes PM2.5, PM10, entre otros.

Quisiera saber cómo puedo cambiar esta variable de contaminantes, y separarla para que cada contaminante sea una variable. Es decir, pasar los datos de esa columna, a una fila con sus respectivos datos.

A continuación comparto una muestra de los datos:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(1199145600, 1199149200, 1199152800, 
1199156400, 1199160000, 1199163600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), Value = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), site = c("AGUINAGA", "AGUINAGA", "AGUINAGA", 
"AGUINAGA", "AGUINAGA", "AGUINAGA"), EnvAut = c("A.M. VALLE DE ABURRA", 
"A.M. VALLE DE ABURRA", "A.M. VALLE DE ABURRA", "A.M. VALLE DE ABURRA", 
"A.M. VALLE DE ABURRA", "A.M. VALLE DE ABURRA"), Latitude = c(6.2531, 
6.2531, 6.2531, 6.2531, 6.2531, 6.2531), Longitude = c(-75.568636, 
-75.568636, -75.568636, -75.568636, -75.568636, -75.568636), 
    AveragingTimeHours = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Year = c(2008, 
    2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008), Var = c("PM2.5", "PM2.5", 
    "PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5"), Units = c("ugm3", "ugm3", 
    "ugm3", "ugm3", "ugm3", "ugm3"), COD_DEP = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 5), NOM_DEP = c("ANTIOQUIA", "ANTIOQUIA", "ANTIOQUIA", 
    "ANTIOQUIA", "ANTIOQUIA", "ANTIOQUIA"), COD_MUN = c(5001, 
    5001, 5001, 5001, 5001, 5001), NOM_MUN = c("MEDELL<cd>N", 
    "MEDELL<cd>N", "MEDELL<cd>N", "MEDELL<cd>N", "MEDELL<cd>N", 
    "MEDELL<cd>N"), StationType = c("Fija", "Fija", "Fija", "Fija", 
    "Fija", "Fija")), spec = structure(list(cols = list(date = structure(list(
    format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"), class = c("collector_datetime", 
"collector")), Value = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
"collector")), site = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), EnvAut = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Latitude = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Longitude = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), AveragingTimeHours = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Year = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
"collector")), Var = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Units = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), COD_DEP = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), NOM_DEP = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), COD_MUN = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), NOM_MUN = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), StationType = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Muchas Gracias por su colaboración.

[image: Adjunto una imagen de referencia a lo que busco realizar]

Comment: Bienvenida, te sugiero que compartas una muestra de los datos, puedes editar tu pregunta y agregar como código el resultado de este comando de R: `dput(head(df)` (`df` es el nombre de tu dataframe) así podremos ayudarte.

Comment: Hola :) Buenas Tardes.
Muchísimas Gracias por la respuesta. 
He colocado el código que me has recomendado y me ha salido lo siguiente, que comparto en la pregunta editada :D

Comment: Genial Laura, ni bien pueda lo miro o alguno de los compañeros de la comunidad

Comment: Muchas Gracias, me sería de gran ayuda que me apoyen con eso, ya que estoy intentando trabajar con el paquete Openair y al parecer no puedo trabajar con él, si no es con el formato que estoy intentando conseguir. Por otra parte el paquete Rcmdr no me permite hacer algunas operaciones estadísticas por ser lista. :( Estaría enormemente agradecida por la ayuda que me puedan brindar, ya que desde hace poco estoy manejando el programa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que lo que buscas es transformar cada valor de `Var` en nuevas columnas y trasladar en ellas el valor de `Value`, ya que usas `tidyverse` puedes aplicar el verbo [`spread()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/spread.html) de esta forma:

```
library("tidyverse")

df %>% 
  spread(Var, Value)
```

Comment: Hola Patricio! :D Muchísimas Gracias por tu ayuda, es exactamente lo que quería obtener. Lo he filtrado según el año para facilitar el análisis, no obstante, en dos años me sale el siguiente error cuando intento usar spread. ~ Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
Keys are shared for 53290 rows~ ¿Sabes cómo podría corregir ese problema para esos años?

Comment: @LauraR, habría que revisar los datos, pero seguramente tiene filas duplicadas, revisa esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898614/how-to-spread-columns-with-duplicate-identifiers/45898919#45898919, básicamente el "workaround" es agregar un número de fila como nueva columna.

Comment: Muchas Gracias Patricio, ya he solucionado el problema. Muchísimas Gracias por tu ayuda, gracias a ti lograré avanzar en mi trabajo de grado. :D