# Agrupar filas iguales de una columna en columnas siendo las filas valores de otra columna en r

Tags: r, dataframe, filtro

Quiero obtener un DataFrame en el que las columnas sean distintos ISIN de fondos de inversión y las filas sus precios con sus respectivos días ordenados (ya que están desordenados). He probado el siguiente código cargando todos los .csv y seleccionando las columnas que me interesan:

```
library(plyr)
library(data.table)

lista_csv = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
datos = ldply(lista_csv, fread)
precios <- select(datos, isin, precio, date)
```

Queda un DataFrame con esta estructura:

```
     ISIN        PRECIO     DATE
1 AT0000A139C4  1092.43   2020-01-07
2 AT0000A139C4  1090.98   2020-01-03
3 AT0000A139C4  1093.49   2020-01-08
4 CH0215804383  98.0236   2020-01-08
5 CH0215804383  98.3556   2020-01-07
6 CH0215804383  98.8268   2020-08-03
```

Y querría un resultado como este:

```
      DATE      AT0000A139C4   CH0215804383 
1  2020-01-03     1090.98        98.8268
2  2020-01-07     1092.43        98.3556
3  2020-01-08     1093.49        98.0236
```

Muchas gracias a todos de antemano

Un saludo

Comment: Hola Pedro! Revisa esta pregunta/respuesta:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/325983/c%c3%b3mo-cambiar-columnas-a-filas/327056#327056 Lo que quieres hacer es un pivot de los datos. PD: Creo que tu pregunta está bien formulada, aunque no presentas código presentas un ejemplo de los datos y del resultado esperado.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta mpaladino. He añadido el código para que se vea la idea que quiero llevar a cabo. También probé el spread() del enlace pero no me ha funcionado, creo que es porque el DF es demasiado largo. Muchas gracias

Comment: Puse una respuesta. Es probable que `spread()` no funcione porque no hay un identificador único de fila. Es bastante común en estos casos, el problema es que al hacer el pivot hay que dar información a la función sobre el orden en el que quieres que queden las filas, sobre todo considerando que puede haber casos en los que el número de filas es diferente entre grupos. A veces tus datos ya tienen una columna que podría servir de `id`, en otros casos en necesario crear una columna ad hoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias maneras de hacerlo. La solución que está más abajo usa la función `pivot_wider()` de la librería `dplyr`. Esta es una función más nueva y complicada (y potente) de `spread()`.

```
library(tidyverse)

read.table(textConnection(
"ISIN         PRECIO
AT0000A139C4 1092.43
AT0000A139C4 1090.98
AT0000A139C4 1093.49
CH0215804383 98.0236
CH0215804383 98.3556
CH0215804383 98.8268"), 
header = T) -> datos

datos %>% 
  group_by(ISIN) %>%      
  mutate(id = 1:n()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = "id", 
              names_from = "ISIN", 
              values_from = "PRECIO")

# A tibble: 3 x 3
     id AT0000A139C4 CH0215804383
  <int>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1     1        1092.         98.0
2     2        1091.         98.4
3     3        1093.         98.8
```

Primero se crean los datos para hacer reproducible al ejemplo.
Un paso intermedio es crear un identificador único que va a controlar el orden de las filas. Quizás en tus datos haya una tercera columna que sirva para esto y en ese caso lo mejor es usarla. Hay casos en los que el orden es muy importante, por ejemplo si vas a hacer cálculos entre columnas. Para la mayoría de las operaciones dentro de una columna el orden importa poco.

En este caso no hay otra columna y asumo que el orden no importa o está bien así como está. Agrupo los datos por `ISIN` y luego, dentro de cada grupo, creo una secuencia que va desde 1 hasta el total de filas dentro del grupo (`1:n()`).

Por último hago el pivot. A la función le indico cuál es el identificador, qué columna aportará los nombres de columnas y cuál los valores.

Con el identificador también funciona `spread()`

```
datos %>% 
  group_by(ISIN) %>%       
  mutate(id = 1:n()) %>% spread(ISIN, PRECIO)
```

Pero prefiero `pivot_wider()` porque es más explícito en la llamada.

## Notas:

Con la búsqueda `[r] spread` en este portal aparecen muchas respuestas a preguntas similares a esta y dan soluciones para variaciones de este problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta y por tu explicación, lo he entendido perfectamente. A mi también me ha ido mejor con pivot_wider().  Un saludo